# CoinGeckoAPI - Format Output - Python

Tags: python

Hi guys i'm working with the Coingecko API to get values from the site.

This is the code

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
cg.get_price(ids=['bitcoin'], vs_currencies='brl')
```

This is the output that's i receive

```
{'bitcoin': {'brl': 221934}}
```

Is there a way to get just the value of the output?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep you can access it like that

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
dict = cg.get_price(ids=['bitcoin'], vs_currencies='brl')
print(dict['bitcoin']['brl'])
```

**output**

`221934`